# Capture stylus signature android

Tags: android, signature, image-capture

I am having a security app requirement where i capture the user signature using the stylus and i want to save that as an image and proceed further. Can anyone please let us know how to create a edittext which takes the strokes we give and saves as text?? Any inputs will be of great help!

Comment: ive seen this if it helps any http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html